# Address Book External Change Callback in Swift (with C Function Pointers?)

Tags: swift, abaddressbook

**Original Question** (see solution below):

I am trying to use the *AddressBook.framework* in my Swift App, but can't figure out how to implement the `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback` function.

**In Objective-C**, I just implement the callback as a C function and pass its pointer:

```
// somewhere in the initializer of the MyAddressBook class:
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil);
ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, externalChangeCallback, (__bridge void *)(self));

// somewhere else in the MyAddressBook class:
void externalChangeCallback(ABAddressBookRef reference, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context)
{
    [(__bridge MyAddressBook *)context addressBookDidChangeExternally];
}

- (void)addressBookDidChangeExternally
{
    // good old Obj-C from here on!
}
```

**In Swift**, it is proving very difficult for me to handle C functions. I found that Apple added the ability to pass C function pointers around in beta 3, but how do I declare such a function? It would be good to use Swift's closure syntax, but is that even possible here?

This is where I create the `ABAddressBookRef`:

```
var addressBookRef: ABAddressBookRef = {
    let addressBookRef: ABAddressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil).takeRetainedValue()

    // TODO: how do I make this work?
    let externalChangeCallback: ABExternalChangeCallback = {
        println("Address book changed externally!")
    }
    ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBookRef, externalChangeCallback, nil)

    return addressBookRef
}()
```

**So how can I implement this in Swift?**

---

**Solution** (with flaws):

As suggested by pNre, this is how I implemented it now:

**In Objective-C:**

*AddressBookExternalChangeCallback.h:*

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
void registerExternalChangeCallbackForAddressBook(ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef);
```

*AddressBookExternalChangeCallback.m:*

```
#import "AddressBookExternalChangeCallback.h"

void addressBookExternalChangeCallback(ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef, CFDictionaryRef info, void *context)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AddressBookDidChangeExternallyNotification" object:nil];
    });
}

void registerExternalChangeCallbackForAddressBook(ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef)
{
    ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBookRef, addressBookExternalChangeCallback, nil);
}
```

**In Swift:**

*after importing bridging header:*

```
registerExternalChangeCallbackForAddressBook(addressBookRef)
```

A notification is posted whenever the address book changes. Only `@objc` classes can register for notifications, though, so **is there a way to call a Swift function or method instead?**

Comment: So how you finished? I did registerExternalChangeCallbackForAddressBook(addressBookRef) in Bridging header and typealias ABExternalChangeCallback = CFunctionPointer<((ABAddressBookRef!, CFDictionary!, UnsafeMutablePointer<()>) -> Void)> declared globally in My swift class Next how to call registerExternalChangeCallbackForAddressBook in Swift ? Please can you post your detail answer for swift that will be really helpful for user like me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ABExternalChangeCallback` is defined as

```
typealias ABExternalChangeCallback = CFunctionPointer<((ABAddressBookRef!, CFDictionary!, UnsafeMutablePointer<()>) -> Void)>
```

From the Xcode release notes:

> However, you cannot call a C function pointer (`CFunctionPointer`) or
>   convert a closure to C function pointer type.

This means you can't assign a block the way you're doing. 
However you can bypass this limitation calling `ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback` in an objc function and calling it from your swift code.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.0

```
if let addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil) {
    let ref = addressBook.takeRetainedValue()
    let callback: @convention(c) (addressBookRef: ABAddressBookRef!, info: CFDictionaryRef!, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void = {
        (addressBookRef, info, context) in

        // do the things you want

    }

    let addressBookChangeCallback = unsafeBitCast(callback, ABExternalChangeCallback.self)

    ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(ref, addressBookChangeCallback, nil)

}
```

Comment: The code construction build and run, but does not fired while any contact changed.

Answer (score 0):

in swift 4.0

```
class ABAddressBookManager: NSObject {

    static let shared = ABAddressBookManager()

    private var addressBook: ABAddressBook?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        let addressBookForObserving = ABAddressBookCreate().takeRetainedValue()
        let context = Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
             ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBookForObserving, { (addressBook, info, context) in 
                guard let context = context else {
                    return
                }
                let manager = Unmanaged<ABAddressBookManager>.fromOpaque(context).takeUnretainedValue()
                //call manager's method
            }
        }
        self.addressBook = addressBookForObserving
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I got the same issue. But I have cleared the cache by calling ABAddressBookRevert() in addressbook object.